# How to properly test a passenger rails app in subdirectory with selenium and capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, passenger

I have a Passenger Rails 4 app running in a subdirectory: `rails4.test/tools/` (rails4.test/ serves up unrelated content).

It works fine when testing manually but I am having trouble getting Capybara and Selenium to place nice. 
In `spec_helper.rb` if I set the app host as such:

```
config.app_host   = 'http://rails4.test/tools'
```

My Selenium tests run fine (i.e. the ones with "js: true"), however I receive routing errors for the ones that do not rely on Selenium. For example, if I have test code that says:

```
visit login_path
```

I'll get the following error:

> No route matches [GET] "/tools/login"

However,  if I set the app host as such:

```
config.app_host   = 'http://rails4.test'
```

I get the opposite problem - the non-selenium tests work fine, but the Selenium tests visit the wrong url (http://rails4.test/controller/action instead of http://rails4.test/tools/controller/action) thus giving 404 errors. I assume the non-selenium tests work okay because the passenger config is routing the requests correctly?

I there an easy way to remedy this? I also attempted to add the following line to my `test.rb` file:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/new_tools'
```

but it did not change anything, regardless of how config.app_host was set.

Is there a way to set the Selenium host separately? Am I doing something stupid?

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I am curious: Are you using RC, or WebDriver?  RC has an interesting concept where you have a Base URL, then when you call `open()`, it will open locations relative to that base url.  For example `open('/test')` will actually open `baseurl.com/test` instead of `http:///test`

Comment: interesting, I'm using WebDriver, it seems to have better support. I guess I could try to RC gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-rc), but I don't actually call make a to `open()`, Capybara does that via `visit`. Maybe it will work?

Comment: no no,  don't downgrade to RC.

Comment: Turns out I couldn't, even if I wanted to: ["Capybara supports Selenium 2.0 (Webdriver), not Selenium RC"](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara#Using_Capybara_with_RSpec)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by detecting if the `:js => true` option was set before each test and adjusting the `app_host` accordingly:

In `spec_helper.rb` in the `RSpec.configure do |config|` block:

```
# adjust app_host depending of if if js == true
config.before(:each) do
  if(example.options[:js])
    Capybara.app_host   = 'http://rails4.test/tools'
  else
    Capybara.app_host   = 'http://rails4.test'
  end
end
```